# Can I create relative filepaths to images in an XCode SDL project?

Tags: sdl, xcode

Can I create relative filepaths to images in an XCode SDL project?

I have to use absolute filepaths as it is, but it would be much easier if I could make the filepaths relative.

Comment: Relative paths work fine. You're probably having a problem where the working directory is not what you expect. Check Xcode's working directory settings.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the working directory worked for me recently:

Go to `Product` -> `Scheme` -> `Edit Scheme`.

Then click `Run` on the left hand panel and then finally enter the path of the files under `Working Directory`.

All of your paths are then relative to the path you entered.

Answer (score 0):

you could place your files in a folder called `resources` or whatever you want it to be at the same directory as the exe. For the file path when using a `SDL_LoadBMP()` or whatnot will be `resources/name_of_image.bmp`

Comment: You could improve this post easily with some formatting and maybe a little extra explanation to the resources folder. Is it automatically referenced as a resource directory? Does the OP need to create any ties to it or is it a relative string he uses that goes relative to his exe? Explain a little further.

Answer (score 0):

XCode usually runs your project from an internal directory used for development.
One easy way to get the path to your program is to query [NSBundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSString * filename = @"images/my_image.jpg";

NSString * resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString * fullPath = [filename stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath];

// fullPath is now the absolute path to the file.
```

You didn't specify the language, but if you are using C++, you can still use Objective-C inside a `.mm` file, in the same project.